# C# Code Contracts build time -- how do I improve it?

Tags: c#, code-contracts, contract

How do I figure out which proofs are the most time-consuming, to be able to help the verifier along with `Assert`s?

Is there any way that is better than guess-and-check?

Answer (score 3):

Sort of. You can find the slowest methods by using the option `-stats slowmethods` (you can also use `-statsOnly` to simplify the log output).

Unfortunately, the output looks like this:

```
Methods taking the longest:
1:   Method #196, 00:00:08.1438107
2:   Method #143, 00:00:07.1916795
3:   Method #68, 00:00:02.2282228
4:   Method #71, 00:00:01.4211421
5:   Method #438, 00:00:01.3781378
6:   Method #452, 00:00:00.8640864
7:   Method #78, 00:00:00.8330833
8:   Method #439, 00:00:00.7390739
9:   Method #72, 00:00:00.5760576
10:  Method #75, 00:00:00.4090409
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to find the method name from the method number.

Answer (score 1):

Use profiler to do that, for example Visual Studio built-in one.
You can reach it from **Analyze** menu. It will show you times and number of occurance for all methods in your code.

Of course there are also third party solutions, for example [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)